# Complex derivative of a composition of functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I need to find $\sin(\ln(\frac{1}{z}+i))$. How do I split up into terms of $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$? I want to use the Cauchy Reimann theory but I am lost in how to apply it to compositions of functions.

Comment: Why "split up"? The chain rule applies as simply for complex variables as for real ones.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to compute this by unraveling it down to real and imaginary parts would be a mistake. You can differentiate this function in exactly the same way would in your first Calculus course, treating $i$ as a constant.  This is justified by the chain rule for holomorphic functions.  The only thing you should be careful about is the domain, since complex logarithms need to be defined with a branch cut.